# Strange problems about multi-thread programming when using global variable

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, global-variables

It is a little strange.My scenarios are as follows:

define two global variables in file A.c:

```
volatile bool g_test = true;
pthread_mutex_t g_test_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

In file A.c the global variable is read only.

```
...
pthread_mutex_lock(& g_test_mutex); 
if(! g_test){
     ret = -1;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(& g_test_mutex);
     goto cleanup;
 }
pthread_mutex_unlock(& g_test_mutex);
...
```

and the global variable is written in another file B.c

```
...
extern volatile bool g_test;
extern pthread_mutex_t g_test_mutex;

bool tmpval = func_to_getval();

if(tmpval != g_test){
   pthread_mutex_lock(& g_test_mutex);
   g_test = tmpval;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_test_mutex);
}
printf("g_test value:%s\n",g_test?"yes":"no");
...
```

The above codes are all Okay.

But it is strange when removing the last printf sentence,the value can not be synced successfully when the g_test is changed and file A.c cannot get the updated value.Why??

Update:

I change the codes:

```
bool tmpval = func_to_getval();

if(tmpval != g_test){
   pthread_mutex_lock(& g_test_mutex);
   g_test = tmpval;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_test_mutex);
}
printf("g_test value:%s\n",g_test?"yes":"no");
```

to

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&g_can_encrypted_mutex);
g_can_decrypted = func_to_getval(env); 
pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_can_encrypted_mutex);
```

It passed.But this will lock the mutex each time and how much cost will be added by using this method?

Comment: Maybe it is because of out-of-order execution of the instructions that modifies the memory. Why don't you try to add a memory barrier  `asm volatile("" ::: "memory");` before assignment to the `g_test` in file `B.c`. Then try to see if the error persists even though you have removed the `printf` you have mentioned.

Comment: @phyloflash shouldn't be necessary, a function call like pthread_mutex_lock() should normally already act as such a memory barrier. After all, the compiler has to assume such calls could modify any memory.

Comment: It's possible that the problem is in some part of the code that's not shown here. Try to show more code. If possible, boil it down to a short but complete program that could be run and tested by others, otherwise people will just be guessing.

Comment: I want to know that should all the global variables be put into the mutex lock sentences.My codes,as you see,I put one out of the mutex lock:if(tmpval != g_test){. see my updates

Comment: If you want to be really portable, then yes, you probably should protect all variables that could be accessed simultaneously by more than one thread (if not by locks, then at least by atomics). But on certain platforms, such as x86, you can get away without locking simple reads or writes, if you're doing it right (variables are properly aligned, compiler can't move code around too much, etc). I think we'd need to see more code to determine how that would work in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B.c should not reference g_test without holding g_test_mutex; two threads could race over this code, and because you read g_test in the if, then update it later, another thread could have come in and updated g_test in the meantime.

That means this original code is wrong:

```
if(tmpval != g_test){  // Access to g_test without mutex
   pthread_mutex_lock(& g_test_mutex);
   g_test = tmpval;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_test_mutex);
}
```

You should keep a copy of g_test in a local variable which you assign when holding the lock; then after releasing the lock, use that local in the printf().

When concurrent programs change behaviour by changing the timing outside of the communicating areas, look for race conditions.

Comment: But another thread in file A.c only reads the global variable in this instance.And g_test = tmpval; is the only write operation for the g_test.

Comment: The value of g_test used in the if statement may change before you execute the pthread_mutex_lock(); so the program has a consistency error.  You need to view this as a transaction, so the if() and assignment appear atomic to an observer.   Similarly the printf might find a different value for g_test than was used in the if or the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Does your program end soon after the `printf` call? Either by the code you've shown as B.c being [near] the end of `main`, or by calling `exit` or similar after the `printf`? If so, it's likely that your program is terminating before the code in A.c gets to run, and the call to `printf` simply delays exit long enough to give it time to run. If this is the case you need to add some exit synchronization - for example, a call to `pthread_join`.

Comment: The codes in B.c are in while loop and does not likely to be terminated..